Handling Multiple File Uploads with Axum
I am developing a web application using Axum and Askama in Rust, where I need to handle multiple file uploads. The frontend uses HTMX for asynchronous requests, and the backend is set up with Axum. However, I am encountering some issues: in Firefox, I get ns_error_net_reset, and in Chrome, it sometimes works and sometimes results in an internal server error. I am also looking for a way to store the uploaded pictures temporarily in memory, ensuring they remain private to each user. Below are the relevant parts of my code:
front end(htmx):
<div class="w-full max-w-xs mx-auto">
  <form id="file_upload" hx-post="/api/upload" hx-encoding="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-4">
      <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="file-upload">
        Upload Images
      </label>
      <input type="file" id="file-upload" name="files[]" multiple accept=".jpg, .png" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" />
    </div>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
      <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" type="submit">
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

and back end:
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    // Initialization code...
    let api_router = Router::new()
        .route("/upload", post(handle_upload).layer(DefaultBodyLimit::max(1024 * 100))); // 100 MB

    // More initialization and server start code...

    Ok(())
}

async fn handle_upload(mut multipart: Multipart) -> anyhow::Result<Html<String>, Response<Body>> {
    while let Ok(Some(field)) = multipart.next_field().await {
        let field_name = field.name().unwrap_or("unnamed").to_owned();
        let data = match field.bytes().await {
            Ok(data) => data,
            Err(e) => {
                return Err(Response::builder()
                    .status(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body(Body::from(format!("Failed to read data for field '{}': {}", field_name, e)))
                    .unwrap());
            }
        };
        info!("Received field: {} ({} bytes)", field_name, data.len());
    }
    Ok(Html("<h1>Upload Complete</h1>".to_string()))
}

Questions:
1.How can I resolve the ns_error_net_reset in Firefox and intermittent internal server errors in Chrome?
2.What would be the best way to store uploaded pictures temporarily in memory, ensuring they are private for each user, without using a database?
Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


this maybe a bug in firefox if you share a reproducer I can test in my local. 2. If you just need the picture in the memory easiest would be hold it in a vector or hashmap and if you have to hold iti in seperate process redis would be easiest way for memory.

